# Boxes don't align properly

Tags: html, css

I have 3 boxes of different sizes. I want to align them like this:

[image: How I want to look]

But all I get is this:

[image: How it looks]

I want to create a windows metro theme website so please help.

```css
header {
 background: url(./bg/bg1.png) 50% 50% no-repeat;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 position: absolute;
 background-size: cover;
}
.box {
 display: inline-block;
 margin: 5px;
 text-align: center;
}
.box img{
 max-width: 40%;
 margin-top: 5px;
 margin-left: 0px;
}
.menu {
 margin: 5px;
}
.boxes1 .box {
 display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
 <header>
 <img src="./img/sweb-logo-new-wh1.png">
 <div class="menu">
  <div class="boxes1" style="width: 48%;">
  <a href="#">
   <div class="box" style="background: #3478e5; width: 50%; height: 300px; margin-bottom: -200px;">
    <img src="./img/user.png">
    <p style="margin-top: 100px; color: white;">Korsinička Zona</p>
   </div>
  </a>
  <a href="#">
   <div class="box" style="background: #34e560; width: 40%; height: 330px; margin-top: -500px;">
    <img src="./img/information.png">
    <p></p>
   </div>
  </a>
  <a href="#">
   <div class="box" style="background: #34e560; width: 30%; height: 200px; margin-top: -900px;">
    <img src="./img/information.png">
    <p></p>
   </div>
  </a>  
  </div>
 </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Why inline styles and css? So confusing

Comment: You can use flexbox or grid layout

Answer (score 0):

As a general tip try to extract inline styles from HTML and transfer to CSS for a better time.

Try flexbox. This is probably not even the best way to do it with flexbox if anyone can improve.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.left {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.box {
  display: block;
  width: 250px;
  outline: 1px solid black;
  background-color: green;
}

.box.teal {
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #36e5f0;
}

.box.pink {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #fc33f3;
}

.box.green {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #8bf221;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    <div class="box teal"></div>
    <div class="box pink"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <div class="box green"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.left-items {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.box {
  display: block;
  width: 250px;
  outline: 1px solid black;
  background-color: green;
}

.left-items .blue-box {
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #3478e5;
}

.left-items .pink-box {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #fc33f3;
}

.right-item .green-box {
  height: 100%;
  background-color:  #34e560;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left-items">
    <div class="box blue-box"></div>
    <div class="box pink-box"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="right-item">
    <div class="box green-box"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```